# Why do we need std::move in constructor's initialisation list?

Tags: c++, c++11

Hi I am reading through Scott Meyer's Effective Modern C++ and in its item 25 it has this example:

```
class Widget {
    public:
    Widget(Widget&& rhs)
    : name (std::move(rhs.name)),
      p(std::move(rhs.p)
    { ... }
    ...
}
```

My question here is why do we need the `std::move` for `rhs.name`? As `rhs` is already a rvalue, doesn't that imply `rhs.name` is also a rvalue so we can safely move it?

Comment: rvalue references are lvalues

Answer (score 2):

As `rhs` has a name, it is no longer a rvalue.

You may then use

```
std::move(rhs.name)
```

or

```
std::move(rhs).name
```

to transform (cast) `name` into a rvalue reference.